# Why is this MySQL query so slow or even blocking further execution?

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization, database-performance

I have a simple MySQL query where i do one LEFT JOIN on a view referencing a table of another schema before i use a conditional statement, searching one column of each of those tables (one virtual).

```
SELECT  *
    FROM  table_a a
    LEFT JOIN  virtual_table_b b  ON a.id = b.id
    WHERE  a.text LIKE '%somestring%'
      OR  b.text LIKE '%somestring%';
```

It works super slow when `somestring` is fairly short and even blocking the whole schema from being used normally.
(Halting it due to heavy processing i guess, the rest of the DB is still working).

The statements on their own are working fine though !

```
SELECT * FROM table_a a LEFT JOIN virtual_table_b b on a.id = b.id;
```

Join seems fine -> takes around 0,04 seconds.

```
SELECT * FROM table_a a WHERE a.text LIKE '%somestring%';
SELECT * FROM virtual_table_b b WHERE b.text LIKE '%somestring%';
```

String matching seems fine too -> take around 0,04 seconds each.

My guess is that since its a left join many values in virtual_table_b are NULL which takes a lot of computation time ?

Both tables have around 40 000 entries with text sometimes being over 60 000 characters.

I am using InnoDB version 5.7.22.

What could be possible reasons why the combined query is so slow and how could i improve that ?

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```sql
    SELECT * 
    FROM table_a a 
    LEFT JOIN virtual_table_b b on a.id = b.id 
    WHERE a.text LIKE '%somestring%'
UNION 
    SELECT * 
    FROM table_a a 
    INNER JOIN virtual_table_b b on a.id = b.id 
    WHERE b.text LIKE '%somestring%';
```

Answer (score 0):

Having `WHERE`clauses on an `OUTER JOIN` can be problematic. Try:

```
SELECT  *
    FROM  table_a a
    LEFT JOIN  virtual_table_b b  ON a.id = b.id
      AND  b.text LIKE '%somestring%'
    WHERE  a.text LIKE '%somestring%'
      OR  b.text is not null;
```